# React Router Links Not Rendering Corresponding Components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm working on a React application with React Router, and I'm facing an issue where clicking on links in my `BaseNav` component is not rendering the corresponding components defined in my routes. I've reviewed the code and couldn't find the problem.

Here's my code:

index.tsx

```
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

if (rootElement) {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <App />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />}>
            <Route index element={<Dashboard />} />
            <Route path="oee" element={<OeeChart />} />
            <Route path="port-count" element={<PortCountChart />} />
            <Route path="production-count" element={<ProductionCountChart />} />
            <Route path="idle-time" element={<IdleTimeChart />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </Provider>,
    rootElement
  );
} else {
  console.error("The 'root' element was not found in the document.");
}

reportWebVitals();
```

Dashboard.tsx

```
import Header from "./Header";
import LeftNav from "./LeftNav";
import RightNav from "./RightNav";

export default function Dashboard() {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* Left Div */}
      <div style={{ float: "left", width: "25%" }}>
        <LeftNav />
      </div>
      {/* Middle Div */}
      <div style={{ float: "left", width: "50%" }}>
        <Header />
      </div>
      {/* Right Div */}
      <div style={{ float: "left", width: "25%" }}>
        <RightNav />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

RightNav.tsx

```
import BaseNav from "./BaseNav";

export default function RightNav() {
  return (
    <div>
      //some other code
      <BaseNav />
    </div>
  );
}
```

BaseNav.tsx

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function BaseNav() {
  return (
    <div>
      <nav className="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
        <Link to="/dashboard/oee" className="nav-item nav-link ">
          OEE
        </Link>
        <Link to="/dashboard/port-count" className="nav-item nav-link">
          Port Count
        </Link>
        <Link to="/dashboard/production-count" className="nav-item nav-link">
          Production Count
        </Link>
        <Link to="/dashboard/idle-time" className="nav-item nav-link ">
          Idle Time
        </Link>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Problem:

When I click on links like `"/dashboard/oee"` or `"/dashboard/port-count"` in `BaseNav`, the corresponding components (`OeeChart`, `PortCountChart`, etc.) are not rendering as expected.

I'm also using Redux for state management, but I don't think it's related to this issue.

Comment: Hello, could you explain why you're using <App /> inside your router? Also, if possible could you make a codesandox or some other example of the issue so we can view the issue in action

Answer (score 0):

The `Dashboard` component, as a layout route component, must render an `Outlet` so its nested routes can be rendered and output their `element` content.

Example:

I'm assuming that neither the left/right navs nor the header are the main content areas and shouldn't render the `Outlet`, but that the middle `div` element ***is*** the main content area. Render an `Outlet` below the `Header`.

```
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from "./Header";
import LeftNav from "./LeftNav";
import RightNav from "./RightNav";

export default function Dashboard() {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* Left Div */}
      <div style={{ float: "left", width: "25%" }}>
        <LeftNav />
      </div>

      {/* Middle Div */}
      <div style={{ float: "left", width: "50%" }}>
        <Header />
        <Outlet /> {/* nested routes render elements here */}
      </div>

      {/* Right Div */}
      <div style={{ float: "left", width: "25%" }}>
        <RightNav />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

For more details see:

- [Layout Routes](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes)
- [Outlets](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#outlets)